# How to change the color of the node-red dashboard chart legend text via custom styling

Tags: node-red

I have a node-red chart dashboard node. I want to change the color of the legend text to white. I know there is the possibility to override the styling of the dashboard via a general style info.

Can somebody help me in figuring out which style element I need to override?

```
.nr-dashboard-chart-container .nr-dashboard-chart chart chart-line {
      color: white !important;
 }
```

This doesn't work and ends up in black text color inside the legend. I want the text to be in white instead.

Via google chrome developer tools the element structure is:

```
<canvas ng-if="me.item.look==='line'" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="config.data" chart-series="config.series" chart-labels="config.labels" chart-options="config.options" chart-dataset-override="config.overrides" chart-colors="config.colours" height="124" width="246" style="display: block; width: 308px; height: 155px;"> </canvas>
```

[image]